How to store generic value-types as nullable
Take the following code (or check it out online):
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new MyNullable<int>();
        var bar = new MyNullable<string>();
        
        foo.Value = 5;
        foo.Value = null; // cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
        
        bar.Value = "Hello";
        bar.Value = null;
    }
}

public class MyNullable<T>{ 
    public T? Value {get; set;} = default;
}

As a workaround I can do new MyNullable<int?>() but that seems unnecessary, given that the nullable annotation is already there.

Why is this a problem?
Is there a fix for it?


nullability tend to not work great with generics, since a nullable reference and a nullable struct are different things. One approach is to use generic restrictions, another to create a custom Option/Maybe type. Since this looks like a toy example it is difficult to suggest alternatives.

@JonasH What do you mean with custom Option/Maybe type?  Isn't this exactly it? Value may have a value or not. This is not really a toy example, there are other fields in the class of no relevance to this question. It boils down to this.

You might want to look at some existing implementations, for example the maybe monad. Most solutions seem to use either polymorphism or Value/HasValue pair to describe if a value exist or not. Using T? is problematic since it means different things for reference and value types. You probably also want to use value semantics for your type, i.e. immutability, value equality, etc.

Are you going to have some nullable T and some non nullable T properties in the the class. If not I don't see a problem going with MyNullable<int?>()
